# Android Studio automatically selecting android resources and not app resrouces

Tags: android, android-studio

every time I try to use something from my resources like a layout file

```
R.id.frameTwo
```

R cannot be found and android studio automatically puts `android.` before the R so it does not find any of my resources and I have errors all over the place.

the error is `Cannot resolve symbol R`

Why cant my resources be found?

Comment: Can you post the specific error your getting?

Comment: @Nick `Cannot resolve symbol R` is the error I get

Comment: Try a gradle clean and build? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18183656/864538

Is this a fresh project?

Comment: @Nick how do you do the gradle cean, the link does not really say. yes the project is new I just copied over a bunch of java and xml files over

Comment: Open command prompt or terminal and cd to your project directory and run gradelw clean. Also which version of Android Studio are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `com.yourpackage.application.R`.

If R.java isn't being properly generated, the problem is in your XML files.  Figure out what's going wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your package is correct at the top. Sometimes Android Studio does weird things.
It could be:

```
package com.yourpackage.applicationname
```

Also check if there is an import statement with R in it. If there is remove it as it's not needed.

Comment: package is fine and there is no R import