# Cannot resolve symbol 'getDefaultAdapter()'?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm using `BluetoothAdapter` in android studio 0.4. Project api minSdkVersion 11.

Main activity look as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bluetoothAdapter = new BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }
}
```

The `getDefaultAdapter` causes:  `Cannot resolve symbol 'getDefaultAdapter()'`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may possibly be relevant (they did a clean of the project in the answer):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-android-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems you should change this

```
bluetoothAdapter = new BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

to

```
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

as the method is a static method.

Comment: That was strange, but android studio was unable to solve this normally itself.

Comment: Sometime tools do behave randomly :)