# Problems with Android Studio! Cannot resolve symbol R, No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm having big problems with Android Studio. I recently made a checkout of a project I've been developing with my friend, and when I open it, all of the R's in the project turn RED ('cannot Resolve Symbol R).

I searched for the answer to this problem, and tried almost everything...Sync Gradle, Grade Clean, etc...Oh, and when I use Build --> Clean Project, it returns 118 errors..Here is the (almost full) console OUTPUT:

```
 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:27: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:35: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:39: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:47: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:59: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:67: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:77: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:39: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:46: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:60: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:87: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:89: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:267: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:269: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:271: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:273: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:259: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:260: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Juliano\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Juliano\Downloads\Compressed\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar -M C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Juliano\Documents\Projects\HueLoc\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.873 secs
```

Yes, that's it..Please, someone help me! (I use W7, Android Studio latest version)

//UPDATE:
I Fixed it by deleting the value.xml file in the 'value21' folder...apparently Android Studio had an update, and this forced me to use the Android L...I changed the version of the appcompat library to 19 ( I was using the 21, so I made a downgrade) in the build.grade of my project (in dependencies)...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-android-studio

Comment: It seems the project uses Material design? If so, make sure you are either using SDK 21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to get the 'R' error all the time. The fix involved the following steps:
-Check build.gradle files for errors or warnings
-Restart Android Studio
-Check for stable version updates
-Open SDK manager and get make sure all new packages and updates are installed
-(sometimes) Rebuilt the project
-Sync gradle