# Java - implementing Youtube Data API (API 19, 4.4)

Tags: java, android, layout, youtube-api

So I'm getting an error in my Java class that tells me that `R` isn't a resolved symbol. I also noticed that whenever I went around online, some of other ppl's codes was slightly different than others and assumed that it was because of the updates and such that's causing these sorts of errors.

In short, I want to know how you call a layout in the Java. `R.layout.activity_main` isn't working and returning an error.

This is the whole code and yes, I'm using someone's code online to see if I can connect my app. Think of it as a small test.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class Search extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

public static final String serverKey = "AIzaSyCuwJyE96NvT62erGiWbMEefVAiQptAmus";
private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
    playbackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("fhWaJi1Hsfo"); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubeView;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;
private MyPlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener;

private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().
        showMessage("Playing");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().
        showMessage("Paused");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.
        showMessage("Stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
        // Called when buffering starts or ends.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {
        // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
        // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
    }
}

private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        // Called when the player is loading a video
        // At this point, it's not ready to accept commands affecting playback such as play() or pause()
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {
        // Called when a video is done loading.
        // Playback methods such as play(), pause() or seekToMillis(int) may be called after this callback.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        // Called when playback of an advertisement starts.
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        // Called when playback of the video starts.
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        // Called when the video reaches its end.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
        // Called when an error occurs.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code segments to your question.

Comment: Just sync your code with gradle, you will get your problem solved

Comment: @Ravi I have, but same issues.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573456/cannot-resolve-symbol-r)?