# How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.
But that's for Mac OS. I am using windows. Every time I create a new project or try to `build/rebuild` the project it  freezes!! I have  installed the latest version(9/10/2016). But things are getting worse. I want to completely remove it and install it as if I would be installing it for the first time. Any help be Appreciated.

Comment: use IOBit Uninstaller then Uninstall and then Powerfull scan and remove all

Comment: @NikunjParadva can I be sure that it won't cause(edit) harm to other softwares  of system softwares?

Answer (score 528, accepted):

To Completely Remove Android Studio from Windows:

**Step 1: Run the Android Studio uninstaller**

The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open the **Control Panel** and under **Programs**, select **Uninstall a Program**. After that, click on "Android Studio" and press **Uninstall**. If you have multiple versions, uninstall them as well.

**Step 2: Remove the Android Studio files**

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in File Explorer, go to your user folder (`%USERPROFILE%`), and delete `.android`, `.AndroidStudio` and any analogous directories with versions on the end, i.e. `.AndroidStudio1.2`, as well as `.gradle` and `.m2` if they exist.

Then go to `%APPDATA%` and delete the `JetBrains` directory.

Also delete the any `AndroidStudio*` directories that are in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google` and `%APPDATA%\Google`.

Finally, go to `C:\Program Files` and delete the `Android` directory.

**Step 3: Remove SDK**

To delete any remains of the SDK, go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and delete the `Android` directory.

**Step 4: Delete Android Studio projects**

Android Studio creates projects in a folder `%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`, which you may want to delete.

Comment: advice number 3 helped me to get rid of 11gb, which were left by android studio. Thanks

Comment: can't find it in the program list :(

Comment: If you don't see %LOCALAPPDATA% you need to show hidden files. You can do this here: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27479

Comment: All developers: "But seriously why would anyone ever need to uninstall MY app."

Comment: My SDK appears to be installed to `C:\AndroidSDK`.  This answer is a couple years old, I wonder if maybe the newer versions install here--or maybe I customized the install.

Comment: @Jonathan You customized your installation, I used standard install and I found every folder he mentioned in the same location.

Comment: Careful there with those rampage.. or it might delete our beloved `Intellij IDE` unintentionally...

Comment: What's missing is AppData/Local/Google, here one might find another AndroidStudio folder with the settings

Comment: You don't need to delete the JetBrains folder, that#s for Rider or Resharper, it has nothing to do with Android Studio

Comment: %AppData%/Local/Google/AndroidStudio*
%AppData%/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio*

Are needed as well

Comment: I started out yesterday with about 27.5 GB free when I installed it. After following this advice, and also uninstalling an unrelated 3.5 GB app, I'm left with 28.5 GB. They only left 2.5 GB of untraceable garbage. Great success!

Comment: This saved me 20GB, I appreciate it!

Comment: not having any luck deleting things from program files seems they are in use by something

Comment: Soo many upvotes. Must be an AS thing. It's killing my PC atm. I wish I could read dump files better.

Answer (score 80):

In **2021**, If you are looking for **uninstall.exe**, the latest Android studio version doesn't come with an uninstaller. Download an older version of the Android studio from the Android studio download archive official **[LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)**; you can download Android Studio 4.1.1.

Download the zip files, extract the uninstall.exe from it, and put it in your Android Studio folder; there is no need to install that older version.

**UPDATE - 04/14/2022**

**Looks like the new version comes with **unistall.exe** now.**

**Tried on** - **Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3 for Windows 64-bit (April 2022)**

Comment: I found uninstall.exe file in above link, under Android Studio 4.1.1. Thanks!

Comment: Why they make it hard to uninstaller thing?

Comment: Working. Thank you

Comment: Downloading a zip of 901 MB just to get one file...

Comment: Bumblebee 2021.1.1 April2022 doesnt have an uninstaller by today

Answer (score 37):

I was having a problem installing the latest v4.1.2 as it was having an issue where after I start it, it shows my old blank project, so the things I did were:

Caution: **Please move your SDK and projects to a separate location before following steps if you haven't. So it might save your time downloading SDKs and stuff.**

1- Uninstall old Android Studio completely (from `Control Panel -> Programs`).

2- Delete this Android Studio folder located at `C:\Users\\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google`

3- Delete this Android Studio folder located at `C:\Users\\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google`

4- Delete these folders (`.android` ,`.AndroidStudio*`, `.gradle`) located at `C:\Users\\<user_name>`

After doing all this, I managed to have fresh updated Android Studio v4.1.2

Comment: I was looking for a way to fully remove Android Studio since it didn't work even after reinstalling. This answer helped me solve the problem, specifically, step 3. The issue was with a plugin that I couldn't remove inside Android Studio. For anyone else having a similar problem, the plugins are located at C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX\plugins where X is the version. Removing this folder will also remove any faulty plugin.

Answer (score 7):

First go to android studio folder on location that you installed it ( It’s  usually in this path by default ; C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio, unless you change it when you install Android Studio). Find and run uninstall.exe file.

Wait until uninstallation complete successfully, just few minutes, and after click the close.

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in File Explorer, go to `C:\Users\%username%, and delete .android, .AndroidStudio(#version-number)` and also `.gradle, AndroidStudioProjects`  if they exist. If you want remain your projects, you’d like to keep  `AndroidStudioProjects`  folder.

Then, go to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming` and delete the JetBrains directory.

Note that AppData folder is hidden by default, to make visible it go to view tab and check hidden items in windows8 and10 ( in windows7 Select Folder Options, then select the View tab. Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.

Done, you can remove Android Studio successfully, if you plan to delete SDK tools too, it is enough to remove SDK folder completely.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary of all paths of leftover files from Android Studio:-**

- C:\Program Files\Android
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Local\Android Open Source Project
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.gradle
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.android
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.konan
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.m2
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Local\Google
- C:\Users\**USERNAME**\AppData\Roaming\Google

Comment: Careful in removing these 2 folders since they can also contain files for Chrome and other Google products: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google, C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Google

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, uninstall Android Studio from the control panel using program and features.
Later you also need to enable displaying of hidden files and folders and delete the following:

`C:/Users/${yourUserName}/AppData/Local/Android`

Comment: My JetBrains folder was under c:\users\ironman\appdata\roaming. Also another Android Studio file that I deleted was "c:\users\ironman\.emulator_console_auth_token".

Answer (score 6):

If you do not have an uninstaller, follow the below steps:

- Download and install an old version of Android Studio (eg: android-studio-ide-191.5977832-windows.exe aka Android Studio 3.5.2) from the [download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).
- Copy (do not cut) and Paste the uninstall.exe from the installed Android Studio folder in your original Android Studio folder. Now, run the uninstall.exe which you just pasted, this will start the uninstall process for your original Android Studio.
- After the original Android Studio is uninstalled, proceed to run the uninstaller in the old version of Android Studio that you downloaded.
- After the old Android Studio is uninstalled, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/8860848) to completely remove any leftover Android Studio related files, folders etc.

Now your system has no Android Studio.

Answer (score 5):

Complementary to the 1st and 2nd upvoted answers, also take a look if anything like `Android Studio` folder remains at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` to avoid wrong references in future installations.

Answer (score 3):

In my case - Windows 10 Home, for removing previous settings, I had to delete `AndroidStudioX` from `C:\Users\<Your User>\AppData\Roaming\Google`  as well.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/3116336 is complete answer but you need to delete also  `%APPDATA%/Local/Google/Android`
folder.

Answer (score 1):

latest Android Studio in 2022, March
**has an uninstall.exe in the root directory.**
For me uninstalling from "Windows Remove Programms View" didn't work, failing with error popup.
But going to the installation directory and just executing uninstall.exe just works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Caution: Please move your SDK and projects to a separate location before following steps if you haven't. So it might save your time downloading SDKs and stuff.

1- Uninstall old Android Studio completely (from Control Panel -> Programs).

2- Delete this Android Studio folder located at C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google

3- Delete this Android Studio folder located at C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google

4- Delete these folders (.android ,.AndroidStudio*, .gradle) located at C:\Users\<user_name>

Answer (score 0):

```
.android
```

check this folder in

> C:\Users\user

its have an issue and fix it then restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a JetBrains customer, then Android Studio can also be installed via the JetBrains Toolbox. In that case, it can be uninstalled from the JetBrains Toolbox (and only from there).

Answer (score -1):

I tried multiple times to get a clean install without success.

I found if I still had the AndroidStudioProjects folder then Android would naturally go to my last project I was working on and start to build that project.

I made a copy of that folder and saved my code to the desktop. Then I deleted the AndroidStudioProjects folder and I had the option of a completely fresh install.

This was done after following this to the letter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/8860848