# How to uninstall a fresh copy of android studio

Tags: windows, android-studio

I recently downloaded Android Studio on my Windows 10 64-bit desktop and I messed up with it every time I open it. It gives me plugin errors and several other errors. I need to uninstall it completely from my desktop. I tried to uninstall it from my desktop and then install it again as if you would do the first time, but it did nothing and now the same problems occur.

How can I manage to remove it completely and install a fresh one again?

Comment: check my answer Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10/39953746#39953746

Answer (score 1):

1. Save your SDK path any text file Uninstall from control panel
2. Find .android directory from C:/Users/**YourUsername**/.. and delete it
3. Delete your SDK
4. Download the latest version of the android studio from here

   https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html Follow installation
   wizard and install SDK from this wizard

Answer (score 0):

Please follow all of the steps below in order.

Run the uninstaller

The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open Control Panel by accessing it from the menu when you right-click the Start Button (This applies for Windows 8 systems). Then, under Programs, select Uninstall a Program. After that, click on Android Studio and press Uninstall. If you have multiple versions, uninstall them as well.

After you have uninstalled Android Studio, it is recommended that you restart before proceeding with the steps below.

Remove the Android Studio files

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in Windows Explorer (The file browser in Windows), type this as the File Path:

```
C:\Users\[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]
```

Replacing [YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME] with the username of your account on Windows. If you don't know your username, navigate to C:\Users and it will list all users on the system.

Here, delete .android, .AndroidStudio and any versions of this directory with versions on the end, .gradle and .m2.

Then, go to

```
C:\Users\Harry\[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\Roaming
```

and delete the JetBrains directory.

Finally, go to

```
C:\Program Files
```

and delete the Android directory.

Remove the SDK

To delete any remains of the SDK, in Windows Explorer, type this in as the File Path:

```
C:\Users\[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\AppData\Local
```

Here, delete the Android directory.

(Optional) Delete all previous projects

If you want to delete any of your previous projects, the directory where your projects are found is the AndroidStudioProjects directory. It is located in your root user file,

```
C:\Users\[YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME]\.
```

Comment: Also remove the .Gradle , . AndroidStudio , and .Android folders from c:\users\(your user name)

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users[Your USERNAME]

Delete Android Studio Folder Such As .android, .AndroidStudio2.2(Your Android Studio Version), AndroidStudioProjects, .gradle

C:\Users[Your USERNAME]\AppData\Local

Delete

> Android Folder