# Unable to install Android Studio

Tags: android

I had Android Studio installed on my system. I downloaded the new Android Studio version 2.2. Instead of uninstalling the old Android Studio i inadvertently removed the complete folder itself and cleaned up  the system. 
Now when i am trying to install the newer version it says that the Android Studio is already running.

I do not have the old folder and that is why i am unable to properly uninstall now.
I tried to find the Android Studio file that might be running in processes to exit it but could not find any such file.
What can i do to install this new version.

Kindly update

Comment: Goto `Control Panel>Program>Uninstall program` and check if studio is listed there.

Comment: it is listed there. but when i click on it it says that folder might be removed or uninstalled

Comment: visit my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10/39953746#39953746

Comment: @Ironman i am unable to run the uninstaller as i have removed the folder. without this uninstallation how can i proceed.

Comment: windows , Linux or Mac ?