# What does mean "specified for property 'resDir' does not exist."

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I build my project. Gradle result is underblock (I'm using data binding in some code)

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task 
>   ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.> Directory 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\"My project loaction"\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\androidTest\debug' specified for property 'resDir' does not exist.

I' try many method (ex: gradle setting, Android stdio setting reset, disable instant run, make just empty directory). but this method is not work for me. Is any Idea of solution?

#### My env

Adnroid stuidio : ver 2.2.3

Gradle : ver 3.2 (use local)

Settings (Build, Execution, Deployment)

- Complier : All 4 check box checked
- Instant Run : Disable

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath "gradle.plugin.me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    //Can lambda expression in android
    apply plugin: "me.tatarka.retrolambda"


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "My project package name"
            minSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {

            // This code block is adding app version at apk file
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            output.outputFile.parent,
                            output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
                }
            }

            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources false
                zipAlignEnabled true
                debuggable false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

        }

        compileOptions
                {
                    encoding = 'windows-1251'// write your encoding here
                    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                }

        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        "Library inclue"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Complete uninstall Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39953495/7017299)

I didn't find any solution or **not work for me**.

So I uninstall all Android studio resource refer to upper link. And reinstall Android studio not contain SDK. (SDK install manually)

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this issue by deleting the .gradle/ directory in the project dir and kicking off a new build.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9. This answer solved the problem.

Comment: This answer solved my problem too.(Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9)

Comment: solved it for me, building from the command line. Although, I used `mv .gradle .broken` rather than deleting, just in case I needed to restore.

Answer (score 4):

Delete root .build and .idea directories. Make project again solved this problem. However it took me 24 mins to build the project.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `build/` directory in my project root and the `build/` directory of all my modules solved it.

Comment: Thank you for reply and up vote you answer. but in my case sometimes not work your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be fixed in **Studio 2.3 Beta 1**.

In my specific scenario invoking `./gradlew :app:installDebug` once after switching flavors fixed the issue temporarily.

Comment: Thank you for replay. But the results are the same.