# Uninstalling Android Studio, but keeping the android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to uninstall the Android Studio, but I want to keep the android SDK. If I uninstall Android Studio, will it also uninstall the android SDK that came with the Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio doesn't come with an SDK, it downloads one from the SDK Manager (Through install wizard on first install as well). you can uninstall and keep SDK.

Comment: Please refer to this answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/66167909/5088314

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few links to the SDK only, which vary based on operating system.

Windows
[https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip)

OSX
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip

Linux
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip

I believe if you manually uninstall the studio, you may still keep the sdk, but if you run the uninstall manager, I believe it will forcibly uninstall all that came with it.

That said you can do a few different things. You can backup the sdk directory so that after uninstall, you still have the sdk, or you can download one of the above packages and use simply just the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Its like Installing Java jdk and installing Eclipse IDE, then uninstalling the Eclipse. Under normal circumstances Only the IDE gets Uninstalled. The JDK is your environment, it will remain in the system. The same goes for Android SDK!