# how to fix NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Every time i try to open new project i got this error even the old ones gives me now this error.

> NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or
>   layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

HELP PLEASE !

Comment: Have you checked all your layout files?

Comment: yes i tried to create new ones but i have the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53061004/10075771 try this.

Comment: i already tried but it does not work my problem is with the new version of android studio 3.2