# Can't start App from Android Studio with neither Launch Option "Default" nor "Specific" Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher

The problem occurred overnight. One day, everything worked fine. I shut my computer down and started it back up on another day. However, without changing a thing, I tried to launch my App on the same virtual device I had before and somehow it wont launch because:

> "Error running 'app'. Default Activity not found."

My manifest looks like this. I changed the package name and the two activities below (see comments below). The rest is exactly the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="MyPackageName">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OneMoreActivity">
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="364e8b3f6acfddf9ad32bed8c1503bb762b19cd5" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

And normally my app would just start with the Login Activity. However, now it does not. I tried to "Invalidate Caches / Restart". Nothing changed. I restarted AS multiple times. Still, nothing.

Then I tried to change the Launch Options. Current Option was set to "Default Activity". So I tried to change it to a specific one. Namely, the LoginActivity. But then it tells me:

> "Error running 'app'. The Activity 'LoginActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml."

It tells me it's not declared, which it clearly is. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to choose it from the dropdown in the first place. I also tried to start on another Activity. "MainActivity". Still nothing.

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a workaround where I can manually get the APK on my virtual device so that I can at least keep working?

### Edit

I already tried deleting the .gradle-folder. Sadly this didn't work. I tried pushing it to git and cloning it again in another folder. That didn't work either.

### Workaround

So far I've only been able to find a workaround:

- Go to Run/Edit Configurations...
- Go to General/Launch Options -> Launch: Nothing
- Run as you normally would. Android Studio will build the project and install the application to your device, **but won't launch it!**
- Launch your app manually on your device.
- Go to Run/Attach Debugger to Android Process.
- Choose your app.

Obviously, that's a little bit of a hassle and might make debugging the start of an app more difficult. So I'm still looking for an actual solution.

Comment: Delete .gradle file and invalidate and restart android studio should solve your problem

Comment: I have same problem, I fix this problem by create new project and copy/pate your code into new one otherwise post on 'GitHub' clone to different machine

Comment: @Smogen can you share the entire manifest file, might be beneficial

Comment: @Nero I added the manifest. As I said, the only change I made before posting is renaming the package to "MyPackageName" and the two activities "AnotherActivity" and "OneMoreActivity". The others have the correct names.

Comment: @Smogen please also share the entire code for the Login activity (from top which also includes your imports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer when I tried to look for a solution to another problem that randomly popped up out of nowhere.

Androidstudio wouldnt load any previews and put warnings in my layouts, because

> One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes.

One solution suggested in 
[the answer I found for that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477738/rendering-problems-note-one-or-more-layouts-are-missing-the-layout-width-or-lay)
was to delete all files in

`C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches`

Thats what I did and it solved both problems. Guess the developers have some fixing to do.