# Android studio unistallation

Tags: android

I was working with android studio 2.3.3. After an update I started getting gradle errors. I wanted to uninstall android studio completely. However android studio was not there in control panel programs. Is it already uninstalled or is there any other procedure?

Comment: Check out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10

Comment: In my control panel, android studio is not visible

Comment: Follow step 2 of the link