# android studio taking 2 days to locate SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Yea, so the title pretty much says it all. But I did take a screenshot..

[I am NEW Here, So I cant Embed Pics yet, you have to click ME to see the PIC.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iWCg.png)

BTW:

I have SD Card Attached to laptop has all my SD Files, Worked Perfectly Before Like 2 Months ago on the same laptop with a few hiccups..

I am Running Windows 10 on A Lenovo Ideapad 100S. (I know this computer is trash no need to tell  me that, but I am pretty sure its capable on developing Mobile and HTML5 Apps.

Thank In Advanced For Anyone taking time to respond. (And Yes, I did check the SD card is fine, it copies & saves other files & plays music clips on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The i/o on an SD card is pretty slow. You have two possible problems. Either the SD card is going bad, or the installation is broken.

I would suggest that you do a full clean reinstall of your android SDK by removing everything and letting the sdk do a fresh install. Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) shows you how to do a reinstall on Windows 10.

> To Completely Remove Android Studio from Windows:
>
> **Step 1: Run the Android Studio uninstaller**
>
> The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open the **Control Panel**
>   and under **Programs**, select **Uninstall a Program**. After that,
>   click on "Android Studio" and press **Uninstall**. If you have
>   multiple versions, uninstall them as well.
>
> **Step 2: Remove the Android Studio files**
>
> To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in File
>   Explorer, go to your user folder (`%USERPROFILE%`), and delete
>   `.android`, `.AndroidStudio` and any analogous directories with
>   versions on the end, i.e. `.AndroidStudio1.2`, as well as `.gradle`
>   and `.m2` if they exist.
>
> Then go to `%APPDATA%` and delete the `JetBrains` directory.
>
> Finally, go to `C:\Program Files` and delete the `Android` directory.
>
> **Step 3: Remove SDK**
>
> To delete any remains of the SDK, go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and delete
>   the `Android` directory.
>
> **Step 4: Delete Android Studio projects**
>
> Android Studio creates projects in a folder
>   `%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`, which you may want to delete.

From [Ironman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6343685/ironman)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the sdk from your Sd card to some folder in your drive and try syncing the sdk from it. if it still, exist download or get new sdk. because some files would be missing in sdk to load it.