# Android Studio is not launching after update from 3.0.1 to 3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was using Android Studio 3.0.1. Today I have updated my IDE to 3.1 (32 bits). After full update, Android Studio is not starting.

I have attached the screen shots of the error [image: Error Screen Shot]

> > ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>
> Java Threads: ( => current thread )
>   =>0x05e77000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10244, stack(0x06490000,0x06590000)]   0x05e76800 JavaThread
>   "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=7420,
>   stack(0x06390000,0x06490000)]   0x05e76000 JavaThread "Java2D
>   Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11024,
>   stack(0x06290000,0x06390000)]   0x038b6800 JavaThread "Service Thread"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12520, stack(0x04920000,0x04a20000)]
>   0x0385cc00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_vm,
>   id=12092, stack(0x04820000,0x04920000)]   0x03857400 JavaThread "C2
>   CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6008,
>   stack(0x04720000,0x04820000)]   0x03854800 JavaThread "C2
>   CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2820,
>   stack(0x04620000,0x04720000)]   0x03853800 JavaThread "Attach
>   Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4548,
>   stack(0x04520000,0x04620000)]   0x03852c00 JavaThread "Signal
>   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9868,
>   stack(0x04420000,0x04520000)]   0x03852000 JavaThread "Surrogate
>   Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13096,
>   stack(0x04320000,0x04420000)]   0x03842000 JavaThread "Finalizer"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13860, stack(0x03f80000,0x04080000)]
>   0x0382b400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=4532, stack(0x03e80000,0x03f80000)]   0x01b3d800 JavaThread "main"
>   [_thread_in_Java, id=10084, stack(0x00050000,0x00150000)]
>
> Other Threads:   0x03827000 VMThread [stack: 0x03d80000,0x03e80000]
>   [id=8028]   0x038ca400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x04a20000,0x04b20000]
>   [id=8568]
>
> VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
>
> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Task Manager, locate Android Studio, right click and select "End Task". Then relaunch Android Studio, this should work. If not, try uninstalling and reinstalling an older version of the SDK. Make sure you [properly uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) the program to avoid any other possible issues with the reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me in the past, I had to update almost everything, specially all SDK versions.

I have no tried this before, but I guess you can re install Android Studio.

Best Regards

Comment: How much Memory Ram do you have? Usually Core Dump fails are because of it.

Comment: In my experience even 8 GB are low. Only can recommend you to try to get more RAM. But if this not work, we should start viewing other options.

Comment: I agreed with you but my OS is 32 bits and 8GB Ram is not supported by the system

Comment: I have tried to install with 8GB RAM but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the past it happened to me too, I solved the problem with un- and reinstall the SDK. I reseted  Android Studio on an older version and updated it.
For me it hellped well. 
If you want you can try it.
Best regards,
Banki

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have already tried this. This method is not working for me.