# Android sdk-manager conflicting with php?

Tags: java, php, android, pear, godot

I need to export to android in Godot Game engine and so I installed the android sdk (command-line tools only) and ran this command:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

And this is what happens:

```
D:\android-sdk\bin>sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\web\asgard\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\web\asgard\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\web\coaster\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\web\coaster\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\123friluft_old\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\arakash\plugins\rainlab\googleanalytics\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\arakash\plugins\rainlab\googleanalytics\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\bitshape\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\fluid\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gaus\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gaus\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox.old\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentlefox\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\gentler\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-file-iterator\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-text-template\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\phpunit\php-timer\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\highpulse\vendor\sebastian\version\build\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'package'.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"http://pear.php.net/dtd/package-2.0", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01}repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01}sdk-addon>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01}sdk-repository>,<{http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01}sdk-sys-img>
Warning: Found corrupted package.xml at D:\storage\dev\www\smakenavdamp\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml
Warning: Invalid package.xml found at D:\storage\dev\www\smakenavdamp\vendor\mockery\mockery\package.xml and failed to parse using fallback.
```

What in the world is going on? :S

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure to clear any messy/wrong configuration by following the answer in this post:

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Remember also that the sdk should live in its own "android" directory. In other words, having the sdk in a path such as `D:\android-sdk` is problematic because it needs the directory above. So put the sdk in a directory like `D:\android\sdk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux I found the same and fixed with the following (get the same error for files under the same *path* of *tools*):

- Create a directory *$HOME/Android/Sdk*
- Under *$HOME/Android/Sdk* unzip the sdkmanager cli (*$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools*)
- Add the following to ~/.profile

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
```

Reload the ~/.profile,

```
source ~/.profile
```

Done