# Failed to open zip file. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Tags: java, android, gradle, zip

I am having trouble getting my project build, always when I press the run button after a while I get this error message.

[image]

I tried several solutions suggested on other posts, for example clearing the .gradle folder, rebuilding the project, cleaning the project, manually downloading the grade files, ... but none have worked for me.

I am using gradle 4.4[image]

Another point worth mentioning is that when looking deeper in the error messages I see this, but I don't know what it means
[image]

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at com.android.builder.dexing.NonIncrementalJarDexArchive.<init>(NonIncrementalJarDexArchive.java:51)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchives.fromInput(DexArchives.java:48)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:88)
... 52 more
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Post your errors as text, not as images.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I updated the post including a part of the error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many listed options in various posts but at the end reinstalling android studio worked for me. I recommend doing this option when nothing else works. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) to do so.