# Android sdk not included with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, download, sdk

Trying to download android studio, i have all the needed requirements for a PC.
Found that i need both jdk and sdk and that sdk should be included with android studio.
First i downloaded and installed jdk.
After downloading android studio from https://developer.android.com/studio/ , everytime i start a new project i get the following error

> Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted

I checked the path of my sdk and found that by default it should be

> C:\Users\elhachem\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Or in Appdata/Local there isn't any folder named Android.. 
Seems like android studio download doesn't contain sdk anymore.
I downloaded latest version of sdk and created the path AppData/Local/Android and i inserted my sdk inside.. Keep on having same error

Comment: Goto Settings-> Appearance And Behaviour -> Android SDK-> Update all the required SDK Tools and Platforms.

Comment: It shows "nothing to show"
I have seen on youtube that there should be a link named launch sdk tools at hte bottom of the window.. its not appearing anymore

Comment: What is your system platform ?

Comment: windows 7 with 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

First check its location from SDK Manager. There you might find a way to solve the problem. If still you have problems, then i recommend you to download to another drive (like D or F). Then again check its location from SDK Manager. If the location is not set, then point it to your new downloaded SDK. And as far as i can tell from the comments your internet connection might not be working properly.

Comment: After adding the path to sdk i got 
"Nothing to do!
Android SDK is up to date."
but when i click finish and try to start a new project I got the same error 
"Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted"

Comment: DId you try changing your SDK location?

Comment: yes 
I tried to call my sdk from downloads, AppData/Local, AppData/Local/Android... 
Always having same error when i start a new project

Comment: Then go to file->Invalidate caches/restart-> Invalidate and restart. Most probably this will solve the problem. And check whether a new project is working or not.

Comment: the android studio file? how to invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: Yes, open Android Studio then click on file at the top left hand side, then click on Invalidate caches/restart. . And please check whether a new project is working or not.

Comment: I have no access to file inside android studio IDE
All i have access to is a pop up "Welcome to android studio" 
When i click "Start a new Android Studio Project", i get "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted."

Comment: Then there should be an option "Configuration" below  "Start a new Android Studio Project", have you tried to open it?

Comment: If you are having problems accessing it too then i recommend you to completely remove android studio ( refer here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/8753545 ) then restart the whole process again. If you still get caught in a problem, i will upload my files.