# Android Studio doesn't ask for the activity selection

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.1.4 doesn't ask for activity selection while opening. When I select to create a Java project, an empty project was created with no main, manifest or gradle files. Even I can't create any activities manually. What should I do?. Here some screenshots. [image] [image]

Comment: After File -> New -> New project you should see a totally different dialog. Something seems to be broken with your AS installation.

Comment: I reinstalled AS but nothing changed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem few weeks ago . I deleted older version of Android Studio and installed latest update from [Google Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and followed all steps for downloading latest SDK and Build tools

Comment: I removed AS with instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10) and I reinstalled. Worked greatly!