# Android Studio Installer stuck on "Patching Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image 13 to 14"

Tags: android, android-studio

Its been an hour but the progress bar does not respond at all even though wifi connection is quite powerful(100Mb/s) and probably stable. I also tried cancelling, restarting and reinstalling twice before but it always gets stuck at this point.
Although this probably did not affect my workflow till now but I would like to keep everything updated and also know why did this happen and any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Got the same s...thing today with "patching google apis intel x86 atom image 28 to 29". On restart, it's "Patching android tv intel x86 atom system image 16 to 17". Again, and nothing, just "please wait until the installation finishes". If Google want to make me appear incompetent due to not keeping deadlines, they're succeeding.

Comment: Did u solve d issue? Please post it it whenever it does.

Comment: For me, interrupting a few times broke some image file. Had to reinstall the SDK (the whole Android Studio, in fact, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746)

Comment: I canceled installation and tried it again. then it worked

Comment: As soon as i've opened this page it got unstuck :D "Intel HAXM updated successfully!"