# Error: org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

[Look my Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV8wr.png)

Why im getting error like this in my build gradle ??

```
org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin
```

**build:sync**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\workspace\New\mrcos-mobile-appv3\MrcosClient\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':MrcosClient'.
> org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

CONFIGURE FAILED

Total time: 0.401 secs
Cause: org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaBasePlugin
```

in the line of:

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\workspace\New\mrcos-mobile-appv3\MrcosClient\build.gradle' line: 1

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'//this is the line 1 that gets error
  apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
  android {
      compileSdkVersion 25
      buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

      defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 15
          targetSdkVersion 25
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0"
          ndk {
              moduleName "mrcosclientndk"
  //            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"

          }
      }
      buildTypes {

          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

          }

      }


      sourceSets {
          main {
              jniLibs.srcDirs =['libs']
              jni.srcDirs = []
          }
      }

      packagingOptions {
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
          exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
          exclude "lib/arm64/libstlport_shared.so"
      }

      dexOptions {
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }
  }


  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is the IDE of Android Studio was corrupted. You must uninstall Android Studio Completely

**To Completely Remove Android Studio from Windows:**

**Step 1:** Run the Android Studio uninstaller

The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open the Control Panel and under Programs, select Uninstall a Program. After that, click on "Android Studio" and press Uninstall. If you have multiple versions, uninstall them as well.

**Step 2:** Remove the Android Studio files

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in File Explorer, go to your user folder (`%USERPROFILE%`), and delete `.android`, `.AndroidStudio` and any analogous directories with versions on the end, i.e. `.AndroidStudio1.2`, as well as .gradle and .m2 if they exist.

Then go to `%APPDATA%` and delete the JetBrains directory.

Finally, go to `C:\Program Files` and delete the Android directory.

**Step 3:** Remove SDK

To delete any remains of the SDK, go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` and delete the Android directory.

**Step 4:** Delete Android Studio projects

Android Studio creates projects in a folder `%USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects`, which you may want to delete.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/10800153) solved my problem.