# Why is UnrealEngine crashing when it calls android.bat?

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, oculus

I'm having problems building for the Oculus Quest using Unreal Engine 4. It calls android.bat and the log says such a process is deprecated.

I already tried Data Build: "on the fly" and "by the book". Prior to this error, Unreal Engine was trying to build with android-28 and I didn't have it. So I downloaded Android Studio, and within it, I downloaded the latest. I opened the Android project and set the SDK to 28. Yet, here is where I get stuck: It is still showing `target=android-19`. I'm not sure if this is the problem, it shouldn't but here is the last trace of information I get from the Unreal Engine build text log.

I already asked online at other forums, but I've found no answers so far.

This is what the log.txt shows after the build failure. You will notice the mention of android.bat:

> Log.WriteException: ERROR: D:/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows/tools/android.bat failed with args --silent update lib-project --path JavaLibs/downloader_library --target android-28Log.WriteException:        (see C:\Users\Cesar Montero\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.22\Log.txt for full exception trace)Log.WriteException: Log.WriteException: BuildException: D:/NVPACK/android-sdk-windows/tools/android.bat failed with args --silent update lib-project --path JavaLibs/downloader_library --target android-28

Based on videos, the build should happen successfully, and I should be able to pick up my headset and test my project. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: I think your android sdk is broken, maybe reinstalling it fix the error.

Comment: That is a good guess. What would be the proper way of uninstalling/reinstalling android?

Comment: follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746) guide to uninstall and then reinstall

Comment: Thank you. I will try again today!

Comment: I re-installed Android, Unreal Engine (source), Windows, and created a new project. I am still getting similar errors even after downloading all the necessary SDK. The problem seems to be rooted in Android Studio setup of gradle. I get the error that **build.gradle** failed because **buildscriptAdditions.gradle** does not exist

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 weeks. I would appreciate some insight into how to solve it.