# Android Studio - App won't open in emulator for an unmodified Basic App template

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and have started a new app (Basic App template with toolbar and floating button). I have enabled Virtualization in my BIOS and have added a Pixel 2 (version 29) emulator.

When I press the Run button, the emulator opens the Pixel 2 and powers on, but the app doesn't open and no icons appear (apart from the standard phone, sms, chrome, playstore icons). I press Run again and still nothing happens (apart from Gradle building).

There are no errors that I can see.

**Edit:** Every now and then when I press Run I see the following error message in Event Log:

```
8:52 AM Error during Sync: Remote object doesn't exist!
```

This only occurs sometimes. Other time, it just says:

```
8:44 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

8:44 AM Gradle build finished in 3 s 972 ms
```

I have tried:

- Deleting the emulator from AVD Manager then creating a new one (Pixel 2, version 29, everything else left as default).
- Deleting the project and creating a new one
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio
- Restarting computer
- Going to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and invaliding then restarting

**Edit 2:**

I was just asked to check `Logcat` in a comment. There is a lot in there but this part is highlighted red and repeats throughout the logs:

```
2019-08-02 08:53:21.707 2031-9184/? E/LoadManifestTask: Can't find Chimera operation impl class com.google.android.gms.walletp2p.infra.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation dropping operation
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.walletp2p.infra.phenotype.PhenotypeCommitIntentOperation" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_extracted_libs/x86, /system/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86, /system/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at ecj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@16910022@16.9.10 (040700-247503114):5)
        at eck.run(:com.google.android.gms@16910022@16.9.10 (040700-247503114):53)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: And when you check via 'Logcat' either by `adb` or the tab in the lower left of Android Studio you see misc log data?

Comment: Post updated with Logcat info. Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. First day using Android Studio (not off to a good start haha).

Comment: I would recommend using API 28 Pie as your emulator for now as the API 29 Q is still in beta. Also identify what PC you have (CPU/memory/OS version/etc.) in case others may have encountered your issue.

Comment: That didn't work either. Now event logs say: `9:28 AM Emulator: Critical: UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(167, 138), size=(375x21), dirty=(375x21 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.) ((null):0, (null))`

Comment: Strange, I would add in details of your PC including what GPU and if you are using multiple monitors. On everything up to date Macbook Air I was able to run an app with a newly created emulator (although it did have a number of Error messages in the log and I had to disable Instant Run for API 28).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very undesirable kind of system bug. Well, the point is here that, sometimes even creating a simple data directory won't work. You would have to go to the source and create a folder yourself. This case is same. Attempting '*Invalidate caches and restating*' isn't working, so you have to do it manually. This is how:

**Solution:**

Close Android Studio

Go to C:\Users\UserName\.android and rename:

- build-cache folder to build-cache.bak

Go to C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio3.4.2\system and rename these folders:

- caches to caches.bak
- compiler to compiler.bak
- compile-server to compile-server.bak
- conversion to conversion.bak
- external_build_system to external_build_system.bak
- frameworks to frameworks.bak
- gradle to gradle.bak
- resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache.bak

Open the Android Studio and open your project again.

Hope it solves your case also. Did for me when I faced the same problem around a year ago.

Comment: I wasn't able to test this as I decided to instead completely uninstall Android Studio (following this guide - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/7040366) then reinstalled while ticking a lot more boxes in the SDK. It's working now.