# Why do I get AAPT Error since Android Studio 3.6.2 update?

Tags: android, aapt

i just updated my Android studio to 3.6.2, now none of my project will compile, I always have the following error:

[...]\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

```
process = AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.2-6040484-windows Daemon #0:
command = C:\Users\sbook\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fa59a1c75ac2c98ba570bfcc63e5c399\aapt2-3.6.2-6040484-windows\aapt2.exe    compile --no-crunch --legacy -o C:\Users\sbook\Documents\Projects\test_app\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug C:\Users\sbook\Documents\Projects\test_app\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
19:31:36.707 [ERROR]     [com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable] AGPBI:     {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":    [{"file":"C:\\Users\\sbook\\Documents\\Projects\\test_app\\app\\src\\main    \\res\\mipmap-    mdpi\\ic_launcher.png"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\sbook\\Documents\\Projects\\test_app\\app\\src\\main\\res\\mipmap-mdpi\\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file     failed to compile.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Even with a new project.

Comment: @ehmunnehm Unless someone comes up with a better idea, I finally made it work by uninstalling (removing) and reinstalling everything: android studio, gradle, the SDKs. For some reason the update messed up with i-dont-know-what. When a reinstall JUST the SDK, i still have the issue. Then I reinstalled GRADLE only, still no change. That's why a removed and reinstalled everything...

Comment: Removing everything and reinstalling did the trick. Followed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Comment: I also made it work by running Android Studio as admin.

Comment: same problem here