# Android Studio : Background task scanning files to index repeats forever

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

background task continuously running with message Updating indices: Scanning files to index.

[Video screen for the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GA53m0lNNShnY5JFCjgLT85yP9uTHp2P/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uninstalling the Android Studio and delete all android studio files form the desk
Then install it again.

[This answer helps me to delete all android studio files for windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)