# Android Studio C++ Support Missing

Tags: android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 3.6.3 on Windows 10 and I created a new Native C++ project. I can build and run the native project and I can debug Java code in the project.

The problems I'm having are:

- I can't step into the C++ code when debugging
- I can't set breakpoints in *.cpp files.
- When I right click folders in the project view to add a new file, I only see options to add Java, Kotlin, and Android platform files. There aren't any options to add C++ source or header files.
- When I open a C++ file Android Studio recommends installing plugins supporting *.cpp. The plugin it's recommending is for Arma 3 plugin development.
- The "Attach Debugger To Process" menu only has Java as a debugger option. That list should also contain Native, Dual, and Auto.

I've made sure to install CMake and NDK (Side By Side) in the SDK Manager and I've configured the NDK in the project settings. I've tried reinstalling Android Studio 3.6.3 and I've also downloaded Android Studio 4.0 RC 1, but I have the same problems.

What steps am I missing to get C++ support in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working. Turns out just running the uninstaller wasn't enough, I had to follow the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746) to completely uninstall Android Studio. I then reinstalled and everything seems to be good.