# Android Studio Canary Build is stuck on Splash Screen on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm stuck on pop-up splash screen with the loading progress indicator at 100%

[image]

I had Android Studio 4.2 Canary 16 previously installed and updated the Kotlin Plugin from 1.4.10 to 1.4.21.  After installing the new version of the plugin I closed and restarted Android Studio which then crashed with error saying that the previous version of the Kotlin plugin failed to be uninstalled.

Subsequent restarts would then always crash Android Studio right before loading my Project.

I then uninstalled both the stable and canary(unzipped folder) Android studio programs and followed the steps as per [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

I then reinstalled the latest Canary build - Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 and then the previous 4.2 Canary 16 but got the same issue on both versions getting stuck in the splash loading screen.

However installing the latest stable 4.1.1 build seems to work just fine. But I need to use the Canary builds to program Jetpack Compose Projects.

Is the canary build generating different files that the stable build does not? If so can I delete them to create to set up a fresh re-install?

Comment: Downloading an older version of the canary build (Android Studio 4.2 Canary 10
Build #AI-202.6397.94.42.6811877) Seems to work

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me alike a file-system permission or exclusive access issue:

> the previous version of the Kotlin plugin failed to be uninstalled

You probably have to manually remove some leftovers from the previous install; on Windows these files are literally distributed all over the place. This may even be required when upgrading stable builds, as I recently had it with the "Fabric for Android Studio" plugin. Launching from the command-line might provide some more clue where it gets stuck (with high probability, when scanning the plugin directory). I've just checked; the Jetbrains Toolbox doesn't even uninstall old versions; `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio` (may vary) is where to find the plugins and where to check for file-system permissions. Also make sure, that the desktop shortcut actually points to the one version to run - or try to run `studio64.exe` directly.

Comment: Running studio64.exe from the command line doesn't output any logs. Looking at the task manager there is an Android Studio background task that 's taking up 0% CPU and around 300MB-500MB memory; killing that closes the splash screen.  I think I've delete all traces of the Jetbrains folder but I'll do some more digging to see if I missed anything. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried by myself and apparently the plugin directory is being shared among several versions of AS - it throws several "Plugin Error", when launching another version. There may be an essential plugin present, which doesn't work in combination with the version of AS to be launched.