# Android Studio setup wizard failed to detect Android SDK Components

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, sdk

today I tried to uninstall Android Studio completely from my Windows10 Machine. (exactly did [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746)). but after trying to install Android Studio again, I faced with this problem. in setup wizard when wizard tried to detect SDK component, it says there is Android SDK installed on system and doesn't let system to get and update right packages.
[image]
[image]

I faced this issue in my other machine with Ubuntu 18.04. I'm sure all files and folders related to Android have been deleted successfuly and I rebooted the machine.
P.S.: If I click `Finish` button I'd go to next step with this hint:
[image]
And if I click Finish again, I'll go to Android Studio main page, but here is `system setting menu` with error on top:
[image]