# Cannot build or run in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was using android studio 4.1.1, I updated to the 4.1.3 version and after that I had some problems.

1. Gradle sync never finished.

[image]

2. the android view (top right) is not showing properly. it appears just like the project view
   [image: Android view]

[image: Project view]

3. The buttons for build, make project and run are not working
   [image]
4. I have errors all around the code.

**What I have tried:**
I tried to upgrade the Gradle to the latest version. but nothing worked
I went to File>Invalidate Caches/Restart. but it did not work
I wanted to Sync project with Gradle files. but that options is not even available (I guess it is due to the Gradle sync still in progress)

I cannot acces the project structure in File>Project Structure (it shows me the error in the snapshot below)
[image: snap for project structure error]

I have been stuck for two days now, and cannot proceed with coding. If anyone can help, I will gladly provide any further information you will need.

Comment: Uninstall your android studio and install again it.

Comment: You can `Invalidate cache and Restart`

Comment: Invalidate cache Restart did not work. I tried reinstalling Android studio and that also did not work. Then I created another project and imported the code from the previous one, and that seemed to work

Comment: What worked for me was to completely uninstall android studio. All the dependencies and then reinstall it again. this question helped a lot : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10#:~:text=Open%20the%20Control%20Panel%20and,versions%2C%20uninstall%20them%20as%20well.]