# Nothing to do! Android SDK is up to date. SDK emulator directory is missing

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, ide, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I decided to completely uninstall android studio to fix problem related with emulator and I have followed the steps on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/4205927), and after I downloaded the last version when I installed it I see this screen

[image]

[image]

android studio see's that an SDK files installed on my device although everything related to the old installation of the program has been deleted, now I need to force AS to download the android SDK again, but I need to know Why it's show there's a remines of old install, and How to fix that

[image]

**Update 01**

After multiple uninstall and reinstalling android studio and all my tries fails to do a fresh install of it with new sdk and tools, I decided to reset my windows system and installed the fresh copy of it but I shocked when I see that the new installed also getting the same error, the AS see that there's installed SDK on my partition even though it's a completely new copy installation of windows, I wondering if the AS keep some hidden/temp files on other partition disk and this casue the problem?!

**Update 02**

I reported this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190893483) to google and it looks it's a general issue, the bug assigned to someone, please star it to attract more attention and quickly solve it

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190893483?pli=1 The issue is now in Won't fix status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete everything first, everything in the user is in the Google file,
there are files for Android, delete them, the old Sdk and the program

```
C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Local\Google

C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Roaming\Google
```

Now go to the Android page to download the Android, but the older version is from the archive

**See the Android Studio release notes.
More downloads are available in the download archives.**

And click on download from the archive or go to the direct link
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
Then look for the version [`Android Studio 3.6.3 April 17, 2020`](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Then click on it and download the appropriate version for your system

Now after the normal install
Download all the appropriate emulators and operating systems for you and all the tools you need
And in the end, go to `updates` and then to `check update`
To download the

> latest version of Android 4.2.1

The problem returns,
but you will now have the required emulators, SDK tools and everything you need.

Comment: I deleted the Google folder, but did not download a old version(just download the newest version), can install SDK.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem even on the latest version of Android studio (Arctic Fox). I even tried to reinstall my Windows but it didn't work. Finally, I figured out my problem is related to the Windows date & time format. I changed it back to "English (United States)" from "Control Panel\Clock and Region\Change date, time, or number formats" and my problem was solved!

Comment: Thank you! I did everything else and nothing worked until I saw your answer. Date & time format did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Step 2 and 3 if you have not already done them after reinstalling Windows

1. Close Android Studio (and **completely** uninstall) and Clear temp files from your System. (press **windows+r** and search for **temp** and **%temp%** folder turn by turn and delete all the files in those folders which you are able to delete). **Temp files might be the reason it detects the remains of older install.**
2. **Download and Install** the JDK from **[here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html)** (you can uninstall any previously installed SDK if you want but it is not necessary).
3. Add the installed JDK to **path as System Variables**. (Adding to path makes the application automatically accessible to everything running on your OS, **this way android studio will automatically detect it**). *If you do not know how to add JDK to path or verify if it was successfully added watch this [tiny video](https://youtu.be/l1VxWWubxFo)*.
4. **Restart the PC**
5. [Install](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) and Start the Android Studio (**as Administrator**) and it should detect the new SDK (it comes with the 933mb android studio you downloaded) automatically but if it does not, refer to the path User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk. Many a times just running as administrator solves these kind of problems.

[image: Must Run as Administrator]

- and no there will be no hidden files on the other disk partition
- and there is never a need to reinstall the OS
- as for the reason why this bug occurred it might be the *temp files* but it is very difficult to point out exactly without being actually present at your computer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall Android Studio
2. Delete folder '.android' in C:\Users"username"\
3. Delete folders 'Android and Android Open Source Project' in C:\Users"username"\AppData\Local\
4. Now install Android Studio and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but on my case I installed android studio before I installed the java JDK. After installing JDK it prompted me the android SDK was missing and android studio installed it itself.