# Stuck in Building Flutter App in my device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Since the system update of my Vivo y20i device, I am having trouble installing my flutter app. When I run (Ctrl+F5) my app it get stuck in `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...` sometimes it is stuck in `Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk`. My developer option is turned on and also the USB Debugging, I tried every solutions that I found here in stackoverflow and other websites:

1. I run the `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew build` and also tried `./gradlew clean build`
2. Uninstall the app in my device then `flutter clean`. I always do the `flutter clean`
3. I uninstall everything, Android Studio and VSCode, and I upgrade my Flutter SDK to 2.5.0, and also did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10).

but I am still facing the same problem. When I try `flutter run -v`, it works but then I can't update my app or do any changes in the app. Please help.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem can be with ADB Server.
Run this:

```
adb kill-server
```

Connect your device again and it should work.

Also

> Settings>>Accounts and sync>>Delete Work Profile or any User Profile created on your phone.

Comment: didn't work too but I guess my problem is really my device.

Comment: The app you are testing was it ever installed on the phone.

Comment: yes, I was able to run the app and then suddenly it is not running anymore just stuck in "Running Gradle assembleDebug" or "Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk". I didn't do anything, all I remember is that my phone system update last friday.

Comment: Is the app is still on your phone? Check in the settings for all applications, this mostly happens because the app remains installed for a different user on the phone. The solution is to go to that app info click the three-dot menu on top and select uninstall for all users.