# Android Studio shows that SDK installed, but it not installed

Tags: android-studio

I had a problem with Android Studio, then I try to delete all related files & folders, and remove Android Studio, to install all things again. I follow: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Now, when I install Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3).
It shows that Android Sdk (Installed), and request me to provide sdk location.. So, there are No installed sdk, I deleted all things, cleaned registry, BUT Android Studio still say its installed!

[image: Android SDK - (Installed)]

What I can do, to convince Android Studio that I want to install SDK also!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search here & there, My friend found that youtube video in Arabic, who described the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRT70VRKsq4

After 4.2.1 update of Android Studio, If your windows language is Arabic, and regional settings (التنسيق الإقليمي وتنسيق الأرقام في ويندوز) is Saudi Arabia (in Arabic).

The Android Studio will show that: SDK installed, & AVD will not work currently, (after application runs on Emulator, the debugger will not connect to app, and no logs will appear).

---

#### Solution:

- Change regional settings to `English (US)`.

in Arabic:

- غير المنطقة إلى الإنجليزية،

from Microsoft support:
[Change the Windows regional settings to modify the appearance of some data types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989)

**Notice:** changing Numbers only to 123456790, will not solve this problem.

Then, all things will work currently, Android Studio will show that SDK not installed & install it, and will show all platform tools, & more.