# Kotlin stdlib unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I had a blue screen some days ago and my Android Studio got broken. It compiles all my kotlin projects without any issues but the entire kotlin stdlib (functions, extension, etc.) are red flag with "unresolved reference" in the editor.
I've tried everthing to solve the issue but failed and I'm running out of ideas to solve it.
Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Go to: File > invalidate caches/restart

Comment: @vadiole Done that already without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I manage so solve my issue by doing a full uninstall of Android Studio by following another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/2076517).