# android studio fail and exit after restore default settings

Tags: android-studio, crash, ide, settings

In order to make an imported project from eclipse into android studio to work, I follow a suggestion from stackoverflow article and do the following;

file -> manage ide settings -> restore default settings

Ｔｈｅｎ　everytimes ａｎｄｒｏｉｄ　ｓｔｕｄｉｏ　ｓｔａｒｔｓ　ａｎｄ　ｆａｉｌ　and exit ｗｉｔｈ　ｔｈｅ　ｆｏｌｌｏｗｉｎｇ　ｍｅｓｓａｇｅ．　Ｈｏｗ　ｔｏ　ｆｉｘ　ｔｈａｔ？

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator' [Plugin: com.intellij]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:218)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:325)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator' [Plugin: com.intellij]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:423)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:60)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:64)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:340)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$loadComponents$5(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$6$loadComponentInEdtFuture$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptProjectResolverExtension
    at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.DisableKaptProjectResolverExtensionInitializer.run(DisableKaptProjectResolverExtensionInitializer.kt:24)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:771)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.idea.KaptProjectResolverExtension PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android, version=2021.1.1 Patch 2, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=50, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 46 more

-----
Your JRE: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after restore default settings (android studio bumblebee patch 2).

I had to uninstall my android studio, if you don't see uninstall.exe on your android studio folder, you can download older version of android studio, and paste uninstall.exe on your root folder, then just uninstall. [Refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048014/7505027)

And download [Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 4](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).
In my case, the problem is solved.