# Android Emulator stuttering + Artifacts (Windows 11 on AMD Processor)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-11, amd-processor

System Specifications:

- Windows 11
- AMD Ryzen 9 5900x
- RTX 2080 TI
- ASUS PRIME x570 PRO Motherboard
- 32GB RAM

The Android Emulator is extremely laggy (No matter the image chosen, I've tried all the way from API 21 to 33 and the problem persists on every image). The animations are not smooth and stutter a lot while animating (It's like they're jumping between the current state and the previous state 1ms ago) and a lot of weird black artifacts show up randomly and I can't even use the recording feature on the emulator (The result is just a black screen)

[image: Black artifact on the emulator]

[image: Black artifact on the emulator 2]

What I've tried:

- BIOS is updated to the latest version (4403)
- Chipset driver for AMD processor updated to the latest version
- Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Virtual Machine Platform are turned off
- Android Emulator Hypervisor for AMD is installed (Through Android SDK)
- Using "Hardware" for emulator graphics
- Reinstalling Android studio
- Reinstalling Android Emulator Hypervisor
- Windows has no updates
- The GPU usage is about 2-3% while running the Emulator
- Running the Emulator in the Tool window or floating window doesn't have an effect
- Tried all the renderers in the emulator settings (Even through terminal)
- Edit: No antivirus installed

Comment: The same here. No matter what I'm using. I saw Your configuration - I have Intel + RTX 2080. Maybe a problem in some conflicts in the driver?

Comment: @don11995 I tried reinstalling the Nvidia drivers too and the AMD cpu drivers, so not really sure..

Comment: I've resolved "black dots" artifacts by disabling "Hardware Accelerated GPU Scheduling" in Windows Display settings. But scrolling stuttering still remains everywhere where the view can be scrolled. But this stuttering is only on emulators with Android 12+.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work :/ @don11995 still getting the black dots and bars

Comment: This seems to be happening only on android 12 emulators.

Comment: @rsanath on Android 13 as well

Comment: See the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73937890/android-studio-emulator-screen-flickers

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on VS2022 17.4.3 based on an Intel i9-7900k w/64Gb RAM, Hyper-V enabled, and an old-but-gold NVidia GTX 1080Ti (driver 577.56) running in two 4k monitors.

What solved my problem? **I just changed the settings of the virtual device from "Auto"-"Auto" to "Angle D3D11"-"Auto"**, as shown below:

[image]

**IMPORTANT:**

1. After changing these settings, you MUST power off the virtual phone and close it.
2. In my case, I also deleted the selected device and reinstalled it from VS2022 (*Tools - Android - Android Device Manager*). The Direct-3D settings was still activated as I had set.

I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I notice same issue. Solved with change emulator Graphics option to **Software - GLES 2.0**
that will fix the glitch issue, but you will notice decrease performance.
this issue has submit to google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241029236?pli=1).

[image]

Comment: there is no such option anymore

Comment: @user924 i have

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that AMD virtualization is enabled in your BIOS. Please post a screenshot of your CPU Performance screen inside Task Manager. I'm looking for it to say that virtualization is enabled, like this:[image]

Also, did you make sure that Hyper-V is completely disabled? And Core Isolation turned off? There are a bunch other apps that could be causing it to turn back on. Please refer to [Google's instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#disable-hyper-v)

Comment: Yep Virtualisation is enabled and yes core isolation is turned off and yeah I did follow the instructions and yup I did make sure hyperv is turned off (through bcdedit too)

Comment: it has nothing to do with that

Comment: also why do I have to disable hyper-v if I want to keep using sub linux on that windows!

Comment: that doc was added for Windows 10 anyway, and it was working fine, the issue with the Windows 11

Comment: also my CPU is Intel and I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

just solved a similar problem, managed to fix after completely uninstalling android studio (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746) and deleting the gvm.sys file from the windows / system 32 / drivers folder