# Android Studio Emulator Screen Flickers

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a new laptop with configuration: -

- List item
- Windows 11 latest build
- Ryzen 7 5800H
- 16GB DDR4 RAM
- RTX 3060 Ti Mobile GPU
- Latest Android Studio
- Latest Android Emulator

I have tried reinstalling the android studio and its emulators but its the same issue. Is this related to the presence of AMD processor ?

I have some ongoing projects which are halted and would like the get this problem fix as soon as possiable.

I have to develop some flutter applications

[Emulator Screen Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4sG7.png)

[Emulator Screen Image 2 Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNzj6.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can resolve this problem changing the render options to ones that best suit your system, test diffent values to find out what is best for you.

[image: Emulator with options screen]

To reach this screen click on the 3 dots at the side of your emulator and then: Settings -> Advanced

Edit: I have used an computer with a Risen 5700G and a RTX3050 with no flickers, so It's probably a configuration issue, also check if you have virtualization enabled on your bios, it'll depend on the manifacturer of your motherboard so I can't provide clear guide on how to enable it on your system, if needed.

Comment: I changer the config and it worked but it is slow so is there any way to increase its responsiveness? I am asking because during installation android studio showed me something about android virtualization on AMD devises which I didn't install!

I have double checked that virtualization is enabled in my laptop

Comment: it's normal to be a little slower than normal because the app will be running on debug mode, but not that much, I guess you may need to try a different config or check at android studio preferences if there's something for AMD that you can install: Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools.

Please let me know if that helps so I'll edit the answer for you so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the current Emulator from .android/avd and install another one such as pixel 4 or pixel 3

Comment: Same problem with old and other ones

Answer (score 0):

It also works if you put the emulator in floating mode. At least it helped for me, and many others with similar problem. On he photos I only see that you have unpinned it, but not set it to "float".

Go to settings, view mode and then float:

[image: Image preview]

I hope it helps, cheers!