# Android Studio Stuck on Loading Start Screen Screen

Tags: android-studio, plugins

This is more of a helpful tip/warning than a question. For someone else that might attempt what I did. Android Studio Dolphin (Not sure about other versions) on Mac and also Windows is stuck on Startup Screen after I installed 5 plugins for CSV support at the same time (Rainbow CSV, Cap-Hadoop, ExcelEditor, ExcelReader, and CSV).

Below is the image of the issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe8rJ.png)

If anyone has a solution that will be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered the same issue today, I was able to fix it by deleting those plugins from the app's data roaming folder, you can access them by typing %APPDATA% in the "Run" app (Windows Key + R) or directly in the folder explorer.

Once there, Google -> AndroidStudio2021.3 (or whatever version you are using) -> Plugins.

EDIT: Mac equivalent is User/Library/Application Support/Google/"version of Android Studio"/plugins
Library might be hidden in User folder so Shift+Command+. to show it
(thanks to TwistenTiger)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks mate, got my Android Studio on Windows working will try on MacOS later. I think it's the Excel Plugins as I accidentally left them and AS Dolphin didn't open, then went back and deleted them and worked.

Comment: Tested on MacOS works now, updated the Mac equivalent. Thank you

Comment: I had the issue after installing plugins directly from AS marketplace to open csv files with some formatting, could be related to Excel though. Glad it worked, you're welcome!

Comment: After a clean uninstall following the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/13642249), I still after a clean install get the endless stuck at the splash screen for android studio Dolphin.

Comment: I want to give 5 ups! cheers