# Android studio 2022.1.1 where is SDK and sdkmanager

Tags: android-studio, sdk, command-line-tool

just installed Android studio 2022.1.1.

Before installation, deleted f:/AppData/local/Android/**
which is very old.

The installer did not install any new SDK?
and command-line tools?

From File > Project Structure: SDK is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To check if you have the latest SDK and command-line tools, you can go to the Android Studio's "SDK Manager" and verify that you have the desired packages installed. If not, you can use the SDK Manager to install the missing components.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. SDK Manager: SDK empty.  SDK update sites: red error, saying could not get manifest.

Comment: By the way, where is command-line tool installed? From the download page, it is bundled in android studio installer.

Answer (score 0):

Android **sdk** not installed. please **re-install sdk** through **SDK Manager**

[image: see image]

if not availabe sdk manager command-line-tool, please check **sdk update sites.**

You can manually **add update sites** url. easily fix this issue.

[image: see image]

Comment: SDK update sites is empty initially. After 15 seconds, two Android repositories show up with error: could not get manifest. What might be the issue? thanks,

Comment: Tried Intellij, search plugins, got connection timeout. Could be similar issue? accessing internet without problem.

Comment: Best solution Please Re-install Android studio.

after unistall.. Please remove android IDE all files and folder's

Please follow the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10

After Install Android studio. works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Best solution Please **Re-install Android studio.**

after unistall.. **Please remove android IDE all files and folder's**

Please follow the below link

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

**After Install Android studio. works perfectly**