# How to completely uninstall Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

Can anybody tell me how to completely uninstall flutter and anything related to it like android studio and sdks from windows because I am facing a lot of problems these days when I try to build an app or even making a new project.

I have already tried to uninstall android studio and reinstall flutter and removing the old flutter path from the environment variables but when I reinstall android studio it is opening the last project I have been working on like I did nothing
So Can anybody tell me how to completely delete anything related to android programming?

Comment: which type of error you are facing?, can you please explain.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/39953495/10157127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because android studio stores some data outside of its installation folder. If you delete android studio then go to AppData/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudioX.X folder and remove that it should remove your android studio settings.

To remove sdks and virtual devices downloaded through android studio go to AppData/Local/Google/Android/Sdk and delete that folder.

If you do this then reinstall android studio it should act as if it is being installed for the first time.

Keep in mind that the sdks and android studio settings may be stored in a different location depending on your install but most likely the settings will be in your AppData folder.