How to set Android Studio targetSdk with no errors or warnings
I have programmed extensively using Android Studio in the past, but I have encountered an issue when trying to create a simple "Empty Views Activity" using Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1 Patch 2 (the latest version available at the time of this writing).  In file build.gradle.kts, I see a warning that I am not targeting the latest version of Android.

However, if I change the value of targetSdk to 35 to match the value of compileSdk, it shows that I have an error.

But ... The app appears to build and to run correctly with either value for targetSdk.  Any suggestions as to how to get rid of this warning/error?

what does the error say? Typically it just telling you that there could be some incompatibilities or changes you may have to make when updating it as a way to make sure you dont just update the number and do nothing else


I see a warning that I am not targeting the latest version of Android

To distribute on the Play Store, you will need to target API Level 35 by sometime in the fall of 2025.  Hence, the warning.

However, if I change the value of targetSdk to 35 to match the value of compileSdk, it shows that I have an error.

The error is that Google thinks that you don't know what you're doing.  If you hover your mouse over the error, the popup should read:

It looks like you just edited the targetSdkVersion from 34 to 35 in the editor. Be sure to consult the documentation on the behaviors that change as result of this. The Android SDK Upgrade Assistant can help with safely migrating...


Choose "Override warning: I know what I'm doing" to suppress the "error". You can get the same option via a quick-fix context action (e.g., Option-Enter with your text cursor in the error).

Thank you for your feedback.  I'm not seeing "Override warning ...".  However, I do see "Suppress EditedTargetSdkVersion with a comment".  When I do that, the error goes away, but I don't ever feel comfortable suppressing an error, and I should not have to do that with a reliable IDE.  I have been programming for many years (I remember when Java was first released by Sun), and I have been programming Android apps since before Android Studio was released; we used Eclipse with a plugin originally.  So far, I have never had to suppress an error signaled by an IDE.

@JohnMoore: To you and me, this "error" is irritating. However, the "error" is not aimed at us, but at those significantly less experienced than us. One size does not fit all, so some things aimed at less-experienced folk will affect us too. IMHO, we need to recognize that and deal with it gracefully. FWIW, I don't think this particular "error" was done well even for newcomers to Android, but I understand what they're trying to address.

Here is some additional information.  When I view settings.gradle.kts, there is another warning under repositoriesMode saying 'getRepositoriesMode' is marked unstable with @Incubating.  Both of these issues were set up initially by Android Studio and not based on changes that I made.  I am tempted to go back to a previous version of Android Studio.

@JohnMoore: Since that particular warning IIRC has been there for a year-plus, you might have to go back a ways. In this case, your concern is with the template used for the new-project wizard. If you do not like the code that wizard generated, change it.

I've wasted enough time on this, including completely uninstalling/reinstalling Android Studio (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10).  I will live with the suppressed warnings, but I don't like it.  These are the kinds of issues that I want my IDE to handle, or at least show me what needs to be changed in order to fix the problem.

The warning: Android studio is asking your app to consider supporting the latest version of Android, ie, Android 15 (API Level 35). Once a new version of Android is released, typically there's a grace period of 1 year for new apps and 2 years for existing apps to update the targetSdk to the latest android version. After that if you don't update to the latest version,

You won't be able to publish new apps. Google play will reject it

If you don't update your existing app to latest targetSdk, your app will become undiscoverable on Google play store. People won't be able to find your app, but your existing users will be able to


The error: Probably a false positive. Try cutting that line and pasting it again. Sometimes Android studio do this and error will go away once you remove the line of code and reinsert. Sometimes it'll go away after compiling. Sometimes it requires us to close and open the file. If it' still there, try restarting Android Studio
Now, if you're able to compile, you're good to go but that doesn't mean your app will work fine on Android 15. Simply changing targetSdk to suggested/required version is not a fool-proof way to update the app to the latest version of Android. Some features may not work as expected when you run the app on devices with latest Android. You need to test it and if anything's broken, update your code accordingly. If everything's fine on an actual device with latest version of android, there's nothing to worry about
