# "cannot resolve symbol R", clean -> build does not work and resource in xml file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to update a 3-year-old Android app and in the process convert from Eclipse to Android Studio. I am also new to android development. I am having troubles with the R files. I have tried the help tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421104/android-studio-marks-r-in-red-with-error-message-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-but), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573456/cannot-resolve-symbol-r) (which aren't all that different I realize). I am referencing strings.

Here is the method:

```
private void setDefaultSettings() {
    SettingsFragment.SETTING_KEY = getResources().getString(R.string.default_key);
}
```

default_key is in my strings.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="default_key">Key1</string>
</resources>
```

I have tried to:

1. Clean and build the project
2. Clean, sync gradle, build project
3. Modify xml files, clean, sync gradle, build
4. Including android.R.string, clean, sync gradle, build

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please, can you put the log?

Comment: maybe the R your using is linking to another project resource ?

Comment: @Remario how would I check that?

Comment: The `R` file should be built provided there aren't any other errors in your code. Have you tried manually including `import com.myproject.R` at the top of your file? (Where `com.myproject` should be replaced with your application package)

Comment: @extmkv do you want the log when I try to compile without an R.java or when I manually add the eclipse R.java to the app path?

Comment: @MichaelDodd that also did not work. The application had originally had that. I have tried with those lines and with removing it.

Comment: Try a manual build from the terminal with `gradlew clean build` - Do any errors or warnings appear in the output?

Comment: @MichaelDodd that was a huge help. I was able to find errors and fix them and now my R.java file is generated. If you convert that to an answer I would mark it as my accepted answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for `R.java` not generating is a failed build, `R.java` is generated from all the IDs and other constants defined in the `/res` folder. If it's unclear as to why `R.java` is not generating, manually build your project by going to the terminal and typing

> gradlew clean build

for Windows, or

> ./gradlew clean build

for Mac or Linux. Any build errors that may have been masked by the IDE's error reporting will be shown in full in the terminal. Once these errors have been fixed, then `R.java` will successfully generate.