# Add Two library in android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

My application was working fine in Android Studio but when i added Library of  google map.Showing an error.

```
package com.iremember.kiet;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; //no error
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;// Cannot Resolve symbol R (when added library of google map)
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

the error " Cannot Resolve symbol R" comming after i added google lib

Comment: What are you asking? Post all of your code.

Comment: when i added google lib its showing 101 errors import com....R is not working but import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; working fine i already done a lot of work in my app plz help

Comment: Why are you adding libs? You are using Android Studio. Post your code and `build.gradle`.

Comment: You need `Clean Project`, check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-android-studio)

Comment: clean my project but no luck@bjiang

Comment: And you may try to change `import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;` to `import com.iremember.kiet.R;`

Comment: @bjiang i already tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1(optional but helpful):

This is **Java** and not **C** or **C++**, stop trying to memorize the imports.

You are using **Android Studio** which is based off **Intellij**, turn on **Optimize Imports**: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/optimizing-imports.html

### Step 2:

Sync and Clean your project.

### Step 3:

Without a doubt, you need to **target** the latest libs, get these from your SDK Manager:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22 // <-- was 18
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0" // <-- was 21.1.2

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22 // <-- was 17
    }

    buildTypes {
                 // <-- debug is debuggable by default
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0' // <-- was 18
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- was 21.0.3
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem and fix it with 
"**sync project with Gradle files**"