# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol 'R' after translating strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I added a translation to the `strings.xml` file so now I have 2 `strings.xml` files, one in hebrew and one in english (the original).
After I did that, suddenly in the `MainActivity.java` file, every time there's `R` in the code, it shows in red color and says

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'R'
```

**I tried all answers in other posts and it didn't help:**

- I tried cleaning the Gradle and sync it.
- There are no xml errors
- After adding `import android.R;` the error disappears but now the same error is shown for all xml file names (for example `toastText = getString(R.string.negativeCups);`, `negativeCups` is in red and shows this error.
- I tried restarting Android Studio
- I tried adding `import com.howtoevery.justjava.R;`
- There are no files named with capital letters in the `Res` folder
- I tried changing the `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`
- I tried adding `import android.R.*`
  and generally, I tried every answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-android-studio) post but nothing worked for me.

The code for the original `strings.xml` file:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">Just Java</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="quantity">Quantity</string>
    <string name="order">Order</string>
    <string name="add">Add another cup of coffee to your purchase</string>
    <string name="reset">Reset calculation</string>
    <string name="decrease">remove 1 cup</string>
    <string name="ordering">You are going to order</string>
    <string name="ordering_cups_price">cups of coffee at a price of</string>
    <string name="empty_order">You can't order nothing, please buy at least 1 cup of coffee</string>
    <string name="resetted">Cups of coffee is already reset.</string>
    <string name="negativeCups">You can't have negative number of cups of coffee</string>
</resources>
```

The code for the translation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="add">תוסיף עוד כוס קפה להזמנה</string>
    <string name="decrease">תסיר כוס אחת</string>
    <string name="hello_world">שלום עולם!</string>
    <string name="order">הזמן!</string>
    <string name="quantity">כמות</string>
    <string name="reset">אפס כמות</string>
    <string name="action_settings">הגדרות</string>
    <string name="ordering">אתה עומד להזמין</string>
    <string name="ordering_cups_price"> כוסות קפה במחיר של </string>
    <string name="empty_order">מה אתה פסיכי? אי אפשר להזמין כלום</string>
    <string name="resetted">משעמם לך? לחצת כבר איפוס יא חופר</string>
    <string name="negativeCups">טוב מה נהיה?? אתה רוצה כבר למכור כוסות?</string>
</resources>
```

**Update:**
I even deleted the folder with the file of the localized `strings.xml` and still I have the same problem.

Comment: have you check is there any error on resource ? or try to rebuild ur project.

Comment: you need to check your resource files. There might be some formating or resource errors.

Comment: show both your strings.xml files.

Comment: @DerGolem
http://i.stack.imgur.com/RWs0R.png and
http://i.stack.imgur.com/fxBo4.png

Comment: those strings.xml file are placed in two separate directory, values for the english one and values-he for the hebrew ?

Comment: @Chris, no, they are both in the `res` -> `values` -> `strings.xml` folder

Comment: That's why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after trying so many things that are related to this `R` problem, I looked at the logCat and saw that there is a problem inside the `strings.xml` file. Apparently I forgot to add the escape sign and this caused the problem, so this is what I had before:

```
<string name="negativeCups">You can't have negative number of cups of coffee<string>
```

and this is the fixed version:

```
<string name="negativeCups">You can\'t have negative number of cups of coffee<string>
```

That's it.. That's what's caused this problem and now it is fixed, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

[image: The values part]

Create two different folder like the values in the picture, one called values for the default one(english) with all the values file and the strings.xml for the english strings and one called values-he with only the string.xml file for the hebrew.

Comment: It doesn't look like this inside of Android Studio, but in Finder it's the same as you described.. I got `values` folder and `values-he` folder and the files in the folders are just as expected (he in hebrew folder and regular in regular folder)

Comment: it's a picture i found on the internet and it's from eclipse but it's the same for android-studio

Comment: Please note that: `Java uses several deprecated two-letter codes. The Hebrew ("he") language code is rewritten as "iw", Indonesian ("id") as "in", and Yiddish ("yi") as "ji".` Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: @Chris, that's not what I'm talking about.. In android Studio it looks like it's in the same folder, but in Finder it's in different folders but it's still doesn't work. I also changed the folder name to iw instead of he and still nothing..

Comment: @Chris
I changed the Android view to Project view and now I see it this way:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/kwwdp.png
Anyways, I still have this problem..