# Android Studio: can´t resolve symbol R

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I know this question has been asked several times, but no answers are useful due to my context. The thing is, I just opened my first project (in my actual computer) all the "R." in the mainActivity.java turn red. Do anyone know what are the causes for this problem and how it can be fixed?

Here is the .java main activity

```
package xyz.elblog.elblog;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.text.Html;
import android.app.Activity;
public class home extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        String readJSON = getJSON("http://blogging.mysite.com.mx/json.php");
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(readJSON);
           String seo = jsonObject.getString("seo");
            WebView bprimary = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bprimary);
            bprimary.loadData(seo,"text/html","UTF-8");
        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

    }

    public String getJSON(String address){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(address);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(home.class.toString(),"Failedet JSON object");
            }
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

therefore this the home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bprimary"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

im trying to get with json html and show on frame layout

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.elblog.elblog"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Comment: i did it but still failing

Comment: Post your build.gradle content, missing libs could show this error.

Comment: dzungpv check the post

Comment: `"Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files" `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: didnt work that option

Answer (score 1):

The problem due to some error in your xml files. So, check all your xml layouts, styles, and selectors for the error. And also check the drawables file names. Like your add some pics in drawables having names containing symbols like '-' etc which is incorrect way to giving name. So, find the error and rebuild your project. This issues will be solved easily.

Comment: It's values-v21. So rename your folder name and rebuild your project.

Comment: Wait! Why are you using this xml file values v-21.xml??

Comment: can i have the code written in this values v-21.xml file?

Comment: i think the probleem goes on targetsdkversion

Comment: i seen your code. You are defining styles in this file. Styles should be defined in res\values\styles.xml file. Or res\values-v21\ styles.xml file for version compatibility.

Comment: how? i just choose blank activity

Comment: But  this problem is due to some error in xml files and name of image drawables you copied in your project. So, check your code throughly. Also, you can try to make the new project and copy your code in that project. Sometimes this works also.

Comment: i did it but still failing

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is any error in res dir's files. So first try to fix those problems(in layout, drawables, styles, values etc etc).
After fixing rebuild your project and the problem will be  solved..
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is no error in XML file, and cross-verify your recent modifications
2. Try "**Sync Project With Gradle Files**"

This has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try compile HttpClient library in your Gradle files like:-

`compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')`