# Android Studio cannot resolve R

Tags: android, resolve

I know this question has been answered before but I checked them all and nothing worked.

I have a simple project that cannot resolve the R sign for some reason.

MainActivity Code

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editname);
            editCode =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcode);
            bSearch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSearch);
}
```

activity_main File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Ελληνικά Προϊόντα"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <TextView android:text="Όνομα"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editname"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:text="Κωδικός Προϊόντος"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editcode"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button   android:id="@+id/bSearch"
        android:text="Αναζητηση"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seth.greekproducts" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="GreekProducts"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

EDIT:
at the error console I am getting:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
```

and dozens of similar errors.

EDIT: Build.Gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Are you importing `com.example.seth.greekprducts.R`?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Thank you for answering. Yes and the R is read at the import too!

Comment: Its a too old question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I know. Whitout a clear solution though...

Comment: @LambrosHitiris Clean and rebuild .Actually R.java is not build .

Comment: Run --> clean project, Run --> Build project. If some errors occur then there are problems into your code

Comment: @LambrosHitiris Post your build.gradle

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya posted!

Comment: @LambrosHitiris See below answer (Anoop M)

Comment: @LambrosHitiris I guess you are newbie in Android .Please add `LAUNCHER` in your manifest tag . Its missing

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have no idea what or where that LAUNCHER is or should be..

Comment: @LambrosHitiris `ndroid.intent.category.LAUNCHER` http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>`

Answer (score 0):

I think You got this error after cleaning the project.If you have errors on xml file it will show error on R.java. So,try to check your xml file has errors.

Comment: I checked them and I posted them here also. I cant find anything wrong.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio, what you have to do usually in this case is clicking on `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

That's the icon on the top right of your screen, the 5th from the right.

Comment: I have tried that. I am getting "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-ldltr-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined"/>
</resources>"

Comment: Does Clean and Rebuild change something? Otherwise it means you have an error in one of your xml files

Answer (score 0):

Do the changes as below in **modules's** **build.gradle**, you have posted **project build** file in your query.

Gradle official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html).

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.package"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    }
```

**style.xml**

```
<!--.......................................MyTheme......................................-->
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Optionals..-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red_primary_color_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/red_placeholder_color</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MaterialEditText</item>
    </style>
    <!--........................................................................................-->
```

Set the above theme in **manifest**.

> Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major
>   version.

Comment: Now it cant find AppCompatActivity and for some reason it can not sync.
Anyway, I dont know why is it so difficult, espcially since I did not change anything from the project start, just the main_activity.xml.
I am starting anew

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hard+work+is+the+key+to+success&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI6POS7cH2yAIVAZmUCh3R6wyf&biw=1366&bih=696