# getPackageName() with Flavors

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the real package name when running a flavored versions of an android app?

I writing and library and in this library I want to get the the app package name for some reason. When I call `getPackageName()` it returns com.example.app.. I want to always get com.example.app without the flavor name. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: There is no "without the flavor name" version of the application ID, if the app developer elects to override the application ID on a per-flavor basis.

Answer (score 1):

This is what used to be the behavior before Gradle plugin 2.x

But when you use e.g. `classpath group: 'com.android.tools.build', name: 'gradle', version: '2.2.1'` then (when using the Linux platform tools - but not on OS X) `getPackageName()` returns the flavor-specific "package" (`applicationId`) instead of what you defined in the app's manifest (`package` field).