# R cannot be resolved to symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time i change `minSDKVersion` from `build.grade` from 8 to 9
i get that `R error`

I checked every single solution been mentioned here

["cannot resolve symbol R" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio)

without fixing it

beside I cant keep `minSDKVersion` to 8 as many things just don`t work with 8

my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kareem.droid1"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
}
```

how to solve it ?

thanks for help

Comment: usually indicates an issue with a resource. there should be other errors before this one.

Comment: there isnt any other error ..i even tried to build new one and also if i changed 8 to 9 i got R error

Comment: Does hitting the button to 'Sync project with Gradle Files' do anything? When you change the minSdkVersion variable, you will need to re-sync with gradle...

Comment: as i said i tried all mentioned in the link which include resync with gradle but no difference

Comment: Why did you make a project that used 8 as the minimum? Or is it an old project?

Comment: no i tried all midSDKVersions and the only one that cause no R error is 8

Comment: But you said in your question that you changed from 8 to 9, and **then** get an error... What exactly are the steps you are following to reproduce the error? Is this a new project or an old one?

Comment: @cricket_007 change gradle.build MinSDKVersion from 8 to 9 that produce error if i tried to change 9 to 8 problem still the same..if i created new one with 8 it works if i changed to 9 it gives error too

Comment: But if you leave it at 8, everything is fine? That is a sign you need to re-sync the project

Comment: i did resync ...beside i need atleast Version to be 9 for some google play services

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: Your project is using `gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'`, so are you sure that with  minSDK 8 your project run fine?

Comment: no thats why i am trying to change it to Version 8 which leads to R error

Comment: I create new project from scratch with your configuration and everything works fine, I just have another two dependencies     `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'` and 
    `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'`

Comment: EDIT: I removed 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` I only have compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' and works fine..

Comment: i will try it but i think its not the problem

Comment: @g2o thank you man ...can you make it an answer to close the question ?

Comment: ok i will do it, glad to help :)

Comment: please mark as solved, if you find my help valuable ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create new project from scratch with your configuration and everything works fine. I just have another two dependencies in my `build.gradle`

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' 
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

**EDIT:** I removed `'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` and still works fine..

> Please check your project dependencies

Hope its helps!!

Answer (score 0):

clean you project after yoy change build.gradle file

Build>clean project

should help.