# Android Studio gradle issue: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command

Tags: java, android

It seems that I am having difficulties with my gradles files on Android Studio, for I am I continuously receiving the message:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit
```

This continously appears on Message Gradle build console that could also be giving me 'Cannot resolve 'R'' error issue that I am also having, thus making it difficult to run my action activity classes

Despite running several Rebuild project attempts, alongside continuously syncing the project with gradle files, I am still bumping into this error. I would be grateful, if someone could take the time in providing debugging solution that would assist me with this problem.

Comment: Please add more of the error to your question. There is not enough information to help

Comment: I hope I have added enough, as shown above.

Comment: I meant more of the Gradle output, not the Java error. Basically, your code can't compile. That's why the R file can't be resolved. You might be able to run `lint` from the Gradle tasks window on the right side of Android Studio to find the problem.

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer to the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31486450/2308683