# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol "R"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my `MainActivity.java` file, I have no errors expect for one that shouldn't be there:

`Cannot resolve symbol R`

My imports are:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Is there an import I am missing that enables `R` to work properly?

Comment: Try Build > Clean Project

Comment: [Duplicate] marked with wrong question as that one mainly concerns Eclipse user and the OP has used android-studio tag. This seems more like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054000/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio?rq=1

Comment: Make sure that the Gradle file is syncing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by first "cleaning project" and then by opening "Tools" then "Android" and then "sync project with grade files"

If that doesn't work try importing the R class in the mainActivity class itself i.e.

Example:
import com.example.androidproject.R;

Here you put your own project domain name and project name i.e. replace com.example with your domain name and androidproject with the project name...p.s. any problem comment below...