# How to add custom font in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

I want to set `fontFamily` to roboto thin of my toolbar title.

I have added roboto thin ttf in `assets/fonts` folder of my android project, however it seems that it is creating issues while running app. I am getting this issue while running

> react-native start

```
ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'E:\Myntra\android\app\build\gener
ated\source\r\debug\android\support\v7\appcompat'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"E:\\Myntra\\android\\app
\\build\\generated\\source\\r\\debug\\android\\support\\v7\\appcompat"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'E:\Myntra\android\app\build\genera
ted\source\r\debug\android\support\v7\appcompat'
    at Error (native)
```

When I am removing the font then it is working fine.
I am unable to fix this issue. What's the reason?

Comment: There is step by step process explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916277/5519329

Comment: Note that if you don't want to use the Postscript name (e.g. `FontName-Bold` which will cause **typefont modifiers** such as `fontWeight` to mismatch the font on Android, in addition to being inconsistent with how fonts are handled on iOS, you should follow up this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70247374/2779871

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. Add your fonts file in

- `Project folder/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/font_name.ttf`

2. Restart the package manager using `react-native run-android`
3. Then you can use your font in your style e.g

- `fontFamily: 'font_name'`

Comment: Do you need any import or require statements to use the font after these steps?

Comment: It works for me without having to do any additional config or import

Comment: what about for ios?

Answer (score 110):

**UPDATE**

Many answers are here for adding custom font in react-native for version < 0.60.

For those who are using **react-native version > 0.60** , **`'rnpm' is deprecated`** and custom fonts will not work.

Now, in order to add custom font in react-native version > 0.60 you will have to :

1- Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the root folder of your project.

2- add this in that new file

```
module.exports = {
project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
},
assets: ['./assets/fonts']
};
```

For those running on **react-native version < 0.69.x**

3- run `react-native link` command in the root project path.

**PS** Make sure you have the right path for the fonts folder before running `react-native link` command

---

**For those running on **react-native version >= 0.69.x**, Since `link` is deprecated so `react-native link` will not work anymore,
the command `react-native link` is replaced by `npx react-native-asset`.**

More info about the release can be seen here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/releases/tag/v8.0.0

Comment: This one here! This is the right answer for 0.60+ version!

Comment: Great answer. One note though: this doesn't work for iOS unless you __also__ change the build system to legacy.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake where can the build system be changed? is it a config somewhere?

Comment: @codin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205221/how-can-i-use-the-legacy-build-system-with-xcode-10s-xcodebuild

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: Here's the complete [tutorial to add custom fonts](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/use-custom-fonts-in-react-native)

Comment: This part is unnecessary and can be removed: `project: { ios: {}, android: {} },`

Comment: @HarshitMadhav as of 0.69.x, the command is `npx react-native-asset` instead of react-native link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872203/unrecognized-command-link-when-linking-fonts-in-react-native

Comment: Don't forget to rebuild your project with `yarn ios` on ios after adding the fonts

Answer (score 51):

Put all your fonts in you React-Native project directory

```
./assets/fonts/
```

Add the following line in your package.json

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": ["./assets/fonts"]
}
```

finally run in the terminal from your project directory

```
$ react-native link
```

to use it declare this way in your styles

```
fontFamily: 'your-font-name without extension'
```

If your font is **Raleway-Bold.ttf** then,

```
fontFamily: 'Raleway-Bold'
```

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted one, it is cleaner and works also for ios.

Comment: For me its not working on android at all. The fonts are present in the `app/src/assets/fonts`. Tried with filename without extension and as well wit font family name which works on iOS.

Comment: This is out of date. `react-native link` shouldn't be used with RN60 and rnpm is being deprecated

Comment: @AmanDeep Refer my answer above it works.

Comment: if you are already using react-native-vector-icons don't forget to remove duplicate files from android assets folder

Answer (score 13):

### Update:

From the [cli docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md), **"rnpm" is deprecated and support for it will be removed in next major version of the CLI.**

Instead, create a `react-native.config.js` in your project folder

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

Put your fonts in ./assets/fonts. Reference your fonts (e.g. McLaren-Regular.ttf) in the styles prop, `{fontFamily: 'McLaren-Regular'}`. If you're using [styled components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components), then `font-family: McLaren-Regular`

No linking or legacy build settings needed for either platforms. If that didn't work (sometimes it doesn't for me), run `npx react-native link`, even if you're using autolinking.

Comment: autolink ---> `Even if you're using autolink`

Comment: Important: do not forget to link and clean!

Comment: Didn't work for me on "react-native": "0.72.4"

Comment: @Ben Butterworth does it need react-native-config package?

Comment: @rusty, no, it doesn't need that

Comment: For latest rn versions, we need to run the "npx react-native-asset" command.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using React Native chances are that you are using [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/index.html) as well. If that's the case, then you can load custom fonts using Expo's [`Font.loadAsync`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts.html) method.

Steps:

1. Put the downloaded font in the `./assets/fonts` directory (if the directory doesn't exist, create it)
2. From the target component (for example: `App.js`) load Expo's `Font` module:

   ```
   import { Font } from 'expo'
   ```
3. Load the custom font using [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     Font.loadAsync({
       'Roboto': require('../assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
     })  
   }
   ```
4. Finally, use the `style` attribute to apply the desired font on a `<Text>` component:

   ```
   <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 38}}>Wow Such Title</Text>
   ```

Comment: Due to Expo's constraint of not being able to *fully run offline, then I think your opening statement is a little, er misleading.. I use both Expo & react-native, Expo is great, but simply doesn't have the features for a lot of common use-cases. Nice answer though

Answer (score 8):

STEP 1:

Create a config file at the root of the project named "**react-native.config.js**"

STEP 2:

Add the following code inside.

```
 module.exports = {
        project: {
        ios:{},
        android:{}
          },
        assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
    }
```

STEP 3:

Run the following command:

```
npx react-native link       (React-native version < 0.69)
npx react-native-asset      (React-native version > 0.69)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Adding Custom Font with EXPO**

If you're using React Native chances are that you are using Expo as well. If that's the case, then you can load custom fonts using Expo's Font.loadAsync method.

Steps

1. Move your font to asset/fonts folder
2. From the target component (for example: App.js) load Expo's Font module:

```
import { Font } from 'expo'
```

3. Set a state

```
this.state = {
   fontLoaded: false
}
```

4. Load the custom font using componentDidMount:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   await Font.loadAsync({
       'ComicSansBold': require('../assets/fonts/ComicSansMSBold.ttf'),
   })

   this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
}
```

5. Finally, use the style attribute to apply the desired font on a  component:

```
{
  this.state.fontLoaded
  ? <Text style={{
    fontSize: 48,
    fontFamily: 'ComicSansBold'
    }}>Glad to Meet You!</Text>
  : null
}
```

Enjoy Coding....

My Output: 
[image: How to add custom font in react native]

Comment: Man that seems like alot of steps

Answer (score 2):

RNPM has been merged into React Native core. This means that you don’t need RNPM anymore. So please they don’t want you to use it. Stop using it.

Here are 7 steps broken down to help you set fonts up:

1. Have your fonts ready, you can download your fonts from GoogleFonts, AdobeFonts, etc. Fonts can be in .ttf, or .otf
2. Create a configuration file in the root of your project for fonts. Create a file called:

   react-native.config.js
3. Create the folder to house your fonts. You can create a folder called fonts inside the assets folder.
4. Paste your .ttf or .otf fonts inside of it.
5. Write a configuration inside of react-native.config.js file, and paste the following:

   module.exports = {
   assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'],
   };

Change the path to the path of the folder housing your fonts.

6. Now natively set the fonts for Android and IOS. You don’t need to manually do that, just run on your terminal:

   react-native link
7. Any new fonts you add, make sure you run react-native link again on your terminal to natively set the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

@nitin-anand's answer was the most appropriate and cleaner than the rest, but that method is now deprecated and now we will have to create a `react-native.config.js` file in our root with the following configuration as an example:

```
module.exports = {
 project: {
  ios: {},
  android: {},
 },
 assets: ['./assets/fonts'], 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set in Project.json:

   ```
   rnpm { 
       assets:assets/fonts
   }
   ```
2. react-native link

Answer (score 1):

For ios:

Add your fonts in given folder structure :

> /assets/fonts

and place your fonts in it .

In the root folder . Add a file named

> react-native.config.js

copy the code and paste

```
module.exports = {
assets: [‘./assets/fonts’]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can easily add Google & custom fonts to react native projects via Expo-font.

**1-Using google fonts in react native:**

import expo-fonts:

```
 import { useFonts, Inter_900Black } from '@expo-google-fonts/inter';
        // install pakages related to your favourite font for example:@expo-google-fonts/roboto & etc.
```

then use this hook at the top of your component hierarchy:

```
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        Inter_900Black,
      });
//fontLoaded indicates the loading state of your font
```

using font:

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter_900Black'}}>Inter Black</Text>
```

**2-Using custom fonts in react native:**

import expo-fonts:

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
```

use this hook at the top of your component hierarchy:

```
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Custom-Font': require('./assets/fonts/Custom-Font.otf'),
  });
```

using font:

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Custom-Font'}}>Inter Black</Text>
```

Comment: The second option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add in project.json file

```
rnpm {
assets:assets/fonts 
}
```

Then perform react-native link

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to create your own custom component for Text and import it from another file.

Assuming you want to change the default font to "opensans-semibold" (that is the name I gave it after downloading it and saving it).

**TYPESCRIPT:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text as DefaultText, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export function Text(props : any) {
    return(
        <DefaultText style={[styles.defaultStyles, props.style]}> {props.children} </DefaultText>
    )
}
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    defaultStyles: {
        fontFamily: "opensans-semibold"
    }
});
```

Now import this anywhere else as:

`import { Text } from './path/to/component'`

and use it as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

#### The correct way

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default props => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 40 }}>Inter Black</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For react-native version above 0.60, create a react-native.config.js file in the root of the directory and add the below code,

```
 module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

And you should also have the assets folder in root of the directory. Then just run the command `npx react-native-asset` in your terminal. This is should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: On Android the file name has to exactly match the Font Family name!**

In my case it wasn't working because the file was named **spectrashell.otf** and the font family name is **Spectrashell**. Only after renaming it to **Spectrashell.otf** it was succesfully linked.

Then add the directory to react-native.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
    project: {
    ios:{},
    android:{}
      },
    assets:['./src/assets/fonts/'],
}
```

and run (if your RN version is version > 0.69)

```
npx react-native-asset
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE for React native 0.69 and above.

In 0.69 version of React Native link command has been removed. react-native-asset  should be used to automatically link the font assets. Just run the following command:

npx react-native-asset

This command links your fonts for Android and iOS

Answer (score -1):

**becareful if assets in src folder**

in react-native.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
project: {
    ios:{},
    android:{}
},
assets: ['./src/assets/fonts']// assets in src folder
// assets: ['./assets/fonts']// if assets in root use this
```

}

Answer (score -2):

For Android :

put your custom fonts in the following folder:

Project folder/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/font_name.ttf

Run react-native run-android

Use the font i your code:

title: { fontSize: 20, fontFamily: " font Name" },

Comment: That's basically a copy of already accepted answer. It does not bring anything new to the question.