# React Native Unrecognized font family not fixing

Tags: ios, react-native

The fonts are in my asset folder, they are also inside xcode copy bundle resources, and also inside resource folder. I already also ran react-native link, but it still doesn't find the font. Is there something I missed? Please see attached images for reference:

[image]

enter image description here

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Font name is not the filename. Try ```Grobold``` as the name or use an app like [BirdFont](https://birdfont.org/) to find the ```real``` name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**React Native Part:**

Add fonts to `assets/fonts` of the **root folder** of `react-native` project

```
react-native-project/
  package.json
  ios/
  android/
  assets/
    fonts/
      GROBOLD...
      ...
```

Add the below snippet to `package.json`

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
  ]
}
```

Run the following command in your `react-native` project to link your assets.

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

[image]

**iOS Part:**

Check `info.plist` for the font files whether they have added already.

[image]

Delete derived data, build and run your Xcode project.

Double check the fonts added to project by navigating to the `AppDelegate.m` file and add these lines of code below `NSURL *jsCodeLocation`;

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  NSLog(@"%@", family);
  for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  {
    NSLog(@" %@", name);
  }
}
```

**Android Part:**

Copy the font files to if they are not exist already.

```
android/
    app/
      src/
        main/
          assets/
            fonts/
              GROBOLD...
```

[image]

Comment: @Vince Gonzales, I've update my answer. Its working for me perfectly. 
Go to step by step as I shown above for better results.
Please let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: for for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  NSLog(@"%@", family);
  for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  {
    NSLog(@" %@", name);
  }
}, how do I run it and where can I check the output of this code?

Comment: Run the Xcode project from **root folder -> ios -> project.xcodeproj**. Also, you can check the logs in the debug console of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out, the weird thing about this error is that I already copied the whole react native project from my friend who is also a mac user, and the fonts are working fine on him, it's only in mine that throws that error.

Comment: The assets folder doens't need to be in the root of the project , also I've only checked Info.plist and then Project > Target > Build phases  Copy bundle resources and the problem was in Copy bundle resources I've added the font file there manually .

Answer (score 4):

Please update below with your code:

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

You missed "/" that's why your compiler didn't find the font file.

Let me know if you still got any issues.

Answer (score 3):

**'rnpm'** is deprecated for version > 0.60 and will be removed completely in major release.

Please follow below steps to start using custom fonts in your react native app

1. Create `react-native.config.js` in root directory
2. Add below code in `react-native.config.js`

   ```
   module.exports = {
     assets: ['./assets/fonts']
   };
   ```
3. In terminal, run `npx react-native link` command
4. Add a style to the  component  `e.g. <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home Screen</Text>`
5. Add a below property to title
   `titleText: { fontFamily: 'name-of-font-without-ttf-extension'}`
6. Run your app `npx react-native run-android / run-ios`
7. You will see the new font added to your app.